# Swift error "Use of undeclared type" in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, researchkit

I'm working on an app using ResearchKit with Swift on Xcode. The ResearchKit software is relatively straightforward, but this particular section of code in view controller has the message:

> "Use of undeclared type"

for all three `ORKTaskViewControllerXXX` types and I'm not sure how to fix it. Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func consentTapped(sender : AnyObject) {
        let ORKTaskViewController = taskViewController(task: consentTapped, taskRunUUID: nil)
        taskViewController.delegate = self
        presentViewController(taskViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension ViewController : ORKTaskViewControllerDelegate {
    func taskViewController(taskViewController: ORKTaskViewController, didFinishWithReason reason: ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReason, error: NSError?) {
        //Handle results with taskViewController.result
        taskViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `import ResearchKit` in the view controller you are calling the `ResearchKit` related stuff.

```
import UIKit
import ResearchKit
```

Comment: Then you have to provide the errors. You can reference to `ResearchKit`'s official samples and see how they implement the features.

Comment: https://github.com/ResearchKit/ResearchKit/blob/ead0650dfbceb83fb20b92a82c4ce3bf14009ecd/samples/ORKSample/ORKSample/OnboardingViewController.swift